# Diplay a <p:confirmDialog> from javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I need to display a `p:confirmDialog` from the JavaScript.

I've tried:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="users"  widgetVar="UsersWidget" severity="alert" closable="false">

    <h:outputText value="Please specify the UserID of the contractor to whom a mail need to be sent"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText></h:inputText>
    <p:commandButton id="OK" value="add"></p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton style="font-size:1.1em;" id="Cancel" 
        value="cancel" action="#{Bean.Report}"   >
    </p:commandButton>

</p:confirmDialog>

<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{Bean.usersList}"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="Other" />
<p:ajax listener="check()" />
```

My Javascript

```
<h:head>
<script language="javascript">
    function check() {
        alert("Entered");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("UsersWidget.show()");
        alert("Working!!");
    }
</script>
</h:head>
```

i can see the alert entered byt i cannot see the conform dialog and the working alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Java and JavaScript.

In your JavaScript, you simply need to do this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function check() {
        alert("Entered");
        UsersWidget.show();
        alert("Working!!");
    }
</script>
```

`UsersWidget` corresponds to the name you set in the attribute `widgetVar` of the `p:confirmDialog`.

If you want to show the dialog after a call to a backing bean, you can call this in your Java code (backing bean):

```
public void myJavaMethod() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("UsersWidget.show()");
}
```

As soon as the request returned, the dialog will be shown.

Comment: Thanks, Now i can show the widget but it is blurred (out of focus).. i cannot perform any operation on that conform dialogue. is there any way to bring the focus to the conform dialogue.